# tabular legend layout for matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I have a plot with 9 lines, representing datasets with two varying parameters, say f_11, f_12, f_13, ..., f_33.  To make the plot (a bit) clearer, I encode the first parameter as the color of the line and the second one as the linestyle (so f_11 is red & dashed, f12 is red & dotted, f21 is green & dashed, f22 is green & dotted, etc.).  So, for the legend, I would like to make a 3x3 table, looking like

```
       | value1 | value2 | value3
---------------------------------
value1 |
value2 |    <artists go there>
value3 |
```

Is there any way I can make this with matplotlib?  An idea would be to make this box with LaTeX, but I need a way to plot the legend artists at the right position.

Thanks!

(crosspossted from matplotlib-users)

Comment: Associated question: [Subheadings for categories within matplotlib custom legend](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21570007/7758804)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Not a very easy question but I figured it out. The trick I use is to initialize an empty rectangle which acts as a handle. These additional empty handles are used to construct the table. I get rid of any excessive space using `handletextpad`:

```
import numpy
import pylab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

im1 ,= ax.plot(range(10), pylab.randn(10), "r--")
im2 ,= ax.plot(range(10), pylab.randn(10), "g--")
im3 ,= ax.plot(range(10), pylab.randn(10), "b--")
im4 ,= ax.plot(range(10), pylab.randn(10), "r.")
im5 ,= ax.plot(range(10), pylab.randn(10), "g.")
im6 ,= ax.plot(range(10), pylab.randn(10), "b.")
im7 ,= ax.plot(range(10), pylab.randn(10), "r^")
im8 ,= ax.plot(range(10), pylab.randn(10), "g^")
im9 ,= ax.plot(range(10), pylab.randn(10), "b^")

# create blank rectangle
extra = Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="w", fill=False, edgecolor='none', linewidth=0)

#Create organized list containing all handles for table. Extra represent empty space
legend_handle = [extra, extra, extra, extra, extra, im1, im2, im3, extra, im4, im5, im6, extra, im7, im8, im9]

#Define the labels
label_col_1 = [r"$f_{i,j}$", r"$i = 1$", r"$i = 2$", r"$i = 3$"]
label_j_1 = [r"$j = 1$"]
label_j_2 = [r"$j = 2$"]
label_j_3 = [r"$j = 3$"]
label_empty = [""]

#organize labels for table construction
legend_labels = numpy.concatenate([label_col_1, label_j_1, label_empty * 3, label_j_2, label_empty * 3, label_j_3, label_empty * 3])

#Create legend
ax.legend(legend_handle, legend_labels, 
          loc = 9, ncol = 4, shadow = True, handletextpad = -2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I know we're not supposed to be chatty on SO, but this is elegant and awesome. Very very nice.

Comment: This is an awesome solution and truly deserves the bounty.

Comment: Thanks, this is really awesome.

Comment: apologize for the question, what is the comma in the plot definition between the name and the equal sign "im1 *,*= "?

Answer (score 13):

Expanding on [The Dude's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25995730/6135182), I've tried to turn this into a **copy-paste solution** by creating a function (see/copy further below) that automates the generation of a table legend such that you only need to add the following instead of `ax.legend()` to your plot:

```py
tablelegend(ax, ncol=3, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), 
            row_labels=['$i=2$', '$i=3$'], 
            col_labels=['$j=1$', '$j=2$', '$j=3$'], 
            title_label='$f_{i,j}$')
```

`row_labels`, `col_labels` and `title_label` are all optional, such that you can e.g. create a legend table with a column header but without a row header.

---

## Full example usage

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()

ax.plot(range(10), np.random.randn(10), "r:", label='$i=1$, $j=1$')
ax.plot(range(10), np.random.randn(10), "g:", label='$i=2$, $j=1$')
ax.plot(range(10), np.random.randn(10), "b:", label='$i=3$, $j=1$')
ax.plot(range(10), np.random.randn(10), "r.", label='$i=1$, $j=2$')
ax.plot(range(10), np.random.randn(10), "g.", label='$i=2$, $j=2$')
ax.plot(range(10), np.random.randn(10), "b.", label='$i=3$, $j=2$')
ax.plot(range(10), np.random.randn(10), "r^", label='$i=1$, $j=3$')
ax.plot(range(10), np.random.randn(10), "g^", label='$i=2$, $j=3$')
ax.plot(range(10), np.random.randn(10), "b^", label='$i=3$, $j=3$')

tablelegend(ax, ncol=3, bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), 
            row_labels=['$i=1$', '$i=2$', '$i=3$'], 
            col_labels=['$j=1$', '$j=2$', '$j=3$'], 
            title_label='$f_{i,j}$')
```

[image]

---

## The `tablelegend` function

```py
import matplotlib.legend as mlegend
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

def tablelegend(ax, col_labels=None, row_labels=None, title_label="", *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Place a table legend on the axes.
    
    Creates a legend where the labels are not directly placed with the artists, 
    but are used as row and column headers, looking like this:
    
    title_label   | col_labels[1] | col_labels[2] | col_labels[3]
    -------------------------------------------------------------
    row_labels[1] |
    row_labels[2] |              <artists go there>
    row_labels[3] |
    
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    
    ax : `matplotlib.axes.Axes`
        The artist that contains the legend table, i.e. current axes instant.
        
    col_labels : list of str, optional
        A list of labels to be used as column headers in the legend table.
        `len(col_labels)` needs to match `ncol`.
        
    row_labels : list of str, optional
        A list of labels to be used as row headers in the legend table.
        `len(row_labels)` needs to match `len(handles) // ncol`.
        
    title_label : str, optional
        Label for the top left corner in the legend table.
        
    ncol : int
        Number of columns.
        

    Other Parameters
    ----------------
    
    Refer to `matplotlib.legend.Legend` for other parameters.
    
    """
    #################### same as `matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend` #####################
    handles, labels, kwargs = mlegend._parse_legend_args([ax], *args, **kwargs)
    if len(extra_args):
        raise TypeError('legend only accepts two non-keyword arguments')
    
    if col_labels is None and row_labels is None:
        ax.legend_ = mlegend.Legend(ax, handles, labels, **kwargs)
        ax.legend_._remove_method = ax._remove_legend
        return ax.legend_
    #################### modifications for table legend ############################
    else:
        ncol = kwargs.pop('ncol')
        handletextpad = kwargs.pop('handletextpad', 0 if col_labels is None else -2)
        title_label = [title_label]
        
        # blank rectangle handle
        extra = [Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="w", fill=False, edgecolor='none', linewidth=0)]
        
        # empty label
        empty = [""]
        
        # number of rows infered from number of handles and desired number of columns
        nrow = len(handles) // ncol
        
        # organise the list of handles and labels for table construction
        if col_labels is None:
            assert nrow == len(row_labels), "nrow = len(handles) // ncol = %s, but should be equal to len(row_labels) = %s." % (nrow, len(row_labels))
            leg_handles = extra * nrow
            leg_labels  = row_labels
        elif row_labels is None:
            assert ncol == len(col_labels), "ncol = %s, but should be equal to len(col_labels) = %s." % (ncol, len(col_labels))
            leg_handles = []
            leg_labels  = []
        else:
            assert nrow == len(row_labels), "nrow = len(handles) // ncol = %s, but should be equal to len(row_labels) = %s." % (nrow, len(row_labels))
            assert ncol == len(col_labels), "ncol = %s, but should be equal to len(col_labels) = %s." % (ncol, len(col_labels))
            leg_handles = extra + extra * nrow
            leg_labels  = title_label + row_labels
        for col in range(ncol):
            if col_labels is not None:
                leg_handles += extra
                leg_labels  += [col_labels[col]]
            leg_handles += handles[col*nrow:(col+1)*nrow]
            leg_labels  += empty * nrow
        
        # Create legend
        ax.legend_ = mlegend.Legend(ax, leg_handles, leg_labels, ncol=ncol+int(row_labels is not None), handletextpad=handletextpad, **kwargs)
        ax.legend_._remove_method = ax._remove_legend
        return ax.legend_
```

Comment: I updated the tablelegend function for newer matplotlib versions. See edit history for older matplotlib versions.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to create a readable table, you can use [PrettyTable](https://code.google.com/p/prettytable/) module

For example in python2.7 this code

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

x = PrettyTable(["City name", "Area", "Population", "Annual Rainfall"])
x.align["City name"] = "l" # Left align city names
x.padding_width = 1 # One space between column edges and contents (default)
x.add_row(["Adelaide",1295, 1158259, 600.5])
x.add_row(["Brisbane",5905, 1857594, 1146.4])
x.add_row(["Darwin", 112, 120900, 1714.7])
x.add_row(["Hobart", 1357, 205556, 619.5])
x.add_row(["Sydney", 2058, 4336374, 1214.8])
x.add_row(["Melbourne", 1566, 3806092, 646.9])
x.add_row(["Perth", 5386, 1554769, 869.4])
print x
```

Can produce this output:

```
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
| City name | Area | Population | Annual Rainfall |
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
| Adelaide  | 1295 |  1158259   |      600.5      |
| Brisbane  | 5905 |  1857594   |      1146.4     |
| Darwin    | 112  |   120900   |      1714.7     |
| Hobart    | 1357 |   205556   |      619.5      |
| Sydney    | 2058 |  4336374   |      1214.8     |
| Melbourne | 1566 |  3806092   |      646.9      |
| Perth     | 5386 |  1554769   |      869.4      |
+-----------+------+------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: No, I want this table to be embedded in the matplotlib figure.  Creating an ASCII table is easy (even if tedious).