# Draw a line on a legend in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw a line on a legend in a plot to separate the top and bottom rows. At the moment the legend looks like the image below

[Image of legend without a line to separate rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qn0CG.png)

Is there any property in plt.legend that can draw a horizontal line or is there any other methods to draw a line in a legend to look like the image below:

[Image of legend with a line to separate rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGJ3Q.png)

Many thanks!

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647370/table-legend-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, an orthodox method would be to separate the legend altogether. 
You may refer to [this link](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html), or refer to the snippet from the same link:

```
line1, = plt.plot([1, 2, 3], label="Line 1", linestyle='--')
line2, = plt.plot([3, 2, 1], label="Line 2", linewidth=4)

# Create a legend for the first line.
first_legend = plt.legend(handles=[line1], loc='upper right')

# Add the legend manually to the current Axes.
ax = plt.gca().add_artist(first_legend)

# Create another legend for the second line.
plt.legend(handles=[line2], loc='lower right')

plt.show()
```

> you will find that only one legend ever exists on the Axes. This has been done so that it is possible to call legend() repeatedly to update the legend to the latest handles on the Axes, so to persist old legend instances, we must add them manually to the Axes: