# matplotlib.pyplot Colormap legend for 2D parameter

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar, colormap, color-mapping

I'm plotting a series of Mean Square Displacement (MSD) log-log plots on the same axes for simulations of self-propelled particles. The simulations run with varying values for the transitive standard deviation, `Dtrans = [0.1, 0.3, 1.0, 3.0, 10]` and for the rotational standard deviation `Drot = [0.1, 0.3, 1.0, 3.0, 10, 30, 100, 300]`, giving a total of 5 × 8 = 40 simulations. Here's what I currently have:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.cm as cmx
import itertools

# List of colour maps
cmaps = ['YlOrRd', 'Greens', 'Blues', 'Purples','RdPu']

nparticles = 5
npts=1000
step=1000
dt = 0.0001

Drot = [0.1, 0.3, 1.0, 3.0, 10, 30, 100, 300]
Dtrans = [0.1, 0.3, 1.0, 3.0, 10]

plt.figure()
plt.title('MSD against time')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('MSD')

# Time steps along horizontal axis:
timeval = np.linspace(0,dt*step*(npts-1),npts)

# For each value of Dtrans
for d1 in range(len(Dtrans)):

    # Choose a colour map:
    colourmap = plt.get_cmap(cmaps[d1])
    # Limit it to the middle 60%
    colourmap = colors.ListedColormap(colourmap(np.linspace(0.2, 0.8, 256)))

    # Get a colour from the map for each value of Drot:
    values = range(len(Drot))
    cNorm = colors.Normalize(vmin=0,vmax=values[-1])
    scalarMap=cmx.ScalarMappable(norm=cNorm,cmap=colourmap)

    for d2 in range(len(Drot)):
        Dr = Drot[d2]
        Dt = Dtrans[d1]
        MSD = np.zeros((npts,))

        x = np.zeros((npts,nparticles))
        y = np.zeros((npts,nparticles))
        for k in range(npts):
            data0=np.loadtxt(open("./Lowdensity/Drot_"+str(Dr)+"/Dtrans_"+str(Dt)+"/ParticleData/ParticleData"+str(k*step)+".csv",'rb'),delimiter=',')
            x0,y0= data0[:nparticles,1],data0[:nparticles,2]
            x[k,:]=x0
            y[k,:]=y0

        for k in range(npts):
            MSD[k] = np.mean(np.mean((x[k:npts,:] - x[0:(npts-k),:])**2 + (y[k:npts,:] - y[0:(npts-k),:])**2,axis=0))

        colorVal = scalarMap.to_rgba(values[d2])

        plt.loglog(timeval,MSD,color=colorVal)
        plt.legend([('Dtrans='+str(i)+', Drot='+str(j)) for [i,j] in np.array(list(itertools.product(Dtrans,Drot)))])

#plt.loglog(timeval, MSDthry(timeval, 0.5, 100, 70, dt*step*npts))
plt.show()
```

[image: log-log plot of MSD against time with nasty legend]

The colormaps work beautifully but my current legend is truly horrid and doesn't fit on the plot. Ideally I want the legend to be five colorbars arranged vertically, with `Dtrans` values along the vertical axis and `Drot` values horizontally. How can I implement this? Thanks!

Comment: You'd create an inset axes with an imshow plot in it that shows the colors you like.

Comment: Did you saw this question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/38647370/12744275 even if it's not exactly what you expect it is a good start I think

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a table can do the work:

```
#initialyze an array at the beginning 
colorsarray = np.empty([5,5] )
for d1 in range(len(Dtrans)):
    ...     
    colorVal = scalarMap.to_rgba(values[d2]) 
    colorsarray[d1, d2] =colorVal

    plt.loglog(timeval,MSD,color=colorVal) 


tab=plt.table(cellText="" , colLabels=Dtrans, 
    rowLabels=Drot, colWidths = [0.2,0.2], 
    loc='higher left', cellColours=colorsarray )
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it myself but for completeness here's my solution.

As in Renaud's solution, I initialise a matrix for the colours, but put them in a heatmap rather than in a table. I'm using `plt.subplot` to plot the heatmap next to the graph.

```
colorsarray = np.empty((len(Dtrans),len(Drot)),dtype=(float,4))

fig=plt.figure()
gs=fig.add_gridspec(3,3)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[:,:-1])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1,2])

for d1 in range(len(Dtrans)):
    ...
    colorVal = scalarMap.to_rgba(values[d2])
    colorsarray[d1, d2] = colorVal

    ax1.loglog(timeval,MSD,color=colorVal)

plt.setp(ax2.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right", rotation_mode="anchor")
ax2.imshow(colorsarray,interpolation=None)
ax2.set_xticks(np.arange(len(Drot)))
ax2.set_yticks(np.arange(len(Dtrans)))
ax2.set_xticklabels(Drot)
ax2.set_yticklabels(Dtrans)
ax2.set_xlabel('D_rot')
ax2.set_ylabel('D_trans')
ax2.axis('equal')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I used [this](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html) article on heatmaps.