# Matplotlib tabular legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a number of datasets that I am trying to plot and I am looking for a tabular way of representing the legend. The plot I am generating is of the following form:

```
mul_list = [1,2,3]
add_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

linestyles = [':','--','-']
linecolors = ['r','g']

time = np.linspace(0,5)

for i,mul in enumerate(mul_list):
    for j,add in enumerate(add_list):
        plt.plot(time,mul*time+add[i],linestyle = linestyles[i],color = linecolors[j])
```

[image]

I am trying to generate a legend of the form:

```
------------------------------
|               'r'     'g'  |
| ':'  m = 1   a = 1   a = 4 |
|'--'  m = 2   a = 2   a = 5 |
| '-'  m = 3   a = 3   a = 6 |
------------------------------
```

where 'r','g' would be markers with the colors red and green, and ':','--','-' would be black markers with the correct style. Is this doable? I have looked around quite a bit and I haven't found a good way of putting two separate sets of markers on a legend in quite this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow for a slight variation, you can create the labels for each combination and use multiple columns:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

mul_list = [1, 2, 3]
add_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

linestyles = [':', '--', '-']
linecolors = ['r', 'g']

time = np.linspace(0, 5)

for i, mul in enumerate(mul_list):
    for j, add in enumerate(add_list):
        plt.plot(time, mul * time + add[i], linestyle=linestyles[i], color=linecolors[j], label=f'm={mul} a={add[i]}')
plt.legend(ncol=len(mul_list))
plt.show()
```

[image: legend with columns]

Plotting in a different order (or manually rearranging the handles and the labels) can give two columns:

```py
for j, add in enumerate(add_list):
    for i, mul in enumerate(mul_list):
        plt.plot(time, mul * time + add[i], linestyle=linestyles[i], color=linecolors[j], label=f'm={mul} a={add[i]}')
plt.legend(ncol=len(add_list))
```

[image: legend with 2 columns]

See also [Table legend in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647370/table-legend-in-matplotlib) if you really want a more complicated legend.

Comment: This is what I had before I started trying to do this. Its not bad but it's not quite as compact and I would like, since there's a lot of extra horizontal space being taken up by the extra markers.

Comment: There is also less vertical space use due to fewer titles. Repeating the markers seems to be easier to understand. Matplotlib's legend API doesn't allow that some columns have markers while other not; the alternative being knitting together multiple legends as in the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647370/table-legend-in-matplotlib).