# Show table legend as columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

Using pandas in a Jupyter notebook with Matplotlib.

Is there any way to format a large legend for readability - such as putting into columns.

I.e.

This ...

[image: formatted legend]

...versus this...?

[image: unformatted legend]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647370/table-legend-in-matplotlib

Comment: `.legend()` has the keyword `ncol=` to specify the number of columns for the legend.