# Tab alignment in legend of Matplotlib Plot

Tags: matplotlib, legend, text-alignment

I would like to create a plot with a legend aligning the text of the different curves. Here is a minimal working example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x=np.linspace(0,10,100)
plt.plot(x,np.sin(x),'-',label=r'1st, second, third, a$_b$')
plt.plot(x,np.cos(x),'--',label=r'fourth, 5th, 5$_{fo}$, sixth')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I want the labels to align in the legend, so get something like:

```
1st     second     third       a$_b$    
fourth  5th        5$_{fo}$    sixth
```

Is there a way of doing this?

[image: plot]

Comment: Yes there probably is a way. What have you tried?

Comment: I searched a lot, but could not find anything, yet... Something like a latex tabular environment might be possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tabular legend layout for matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830780/tabular-legend-layout-for-matplotlib)

Comment: I looked at this, but this is not exactly what I want, I think

Comment: @DavidG If that is truly helpful for the solution, please post an answer here. I think it will be helpful for many people having a similar problem

Answer (score 4):

An easy option would be to use a monospace font and fill the required space with blanks.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x=np.linspace(0,10,100)
plt.plot(x,np.sin(x),'-', label='1st     second   third   a$_b$')
plt.plot(x,np.cos(x),'--',label='fourth  5th      5$_{fo}$      sixth')
plt.legend(prop={'family': 'DejaVu Sans Mono'})
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Well, this is not really what I was looking for. I was searching for an automated solution, I don't really want to put in the spaces by hand, nor do I want to use a monospace font (would like to use latex equations also)

Comment: There is a link in the comments above to a similar question the solution to which you may adapt for your case. The answer here is just to show a quick and dirty way, in case the linked answer would be too complicated to implement.

Comment: any idea on how to achieve the same if you are using ''text.usetex' in 'rcParams'?

Comment: doesn't work using "annotate" for example...