# Matplotlib legends with multiple curves per line

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I've included two potential plot legend styles below.  The first, where each curve/marker gets its own description, is pretty typical in matplotlib.  But is there a way in matplotlib to achieve the second plot legend, where multiple curves are combined into one line of description?  Thank you!

[image]

Comment: It's sure possible. You may start by reading the [legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html) and search for similar questions on SO.

Comment: You have to make your ouw legend marker. I.e., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38647370/table-legend-in-matplotlib

Comment: I've created a tablelegend function [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60345118/6135182) that might be useful for this purpose. You can use it without `col_labels` for the plots here.