# Have two plots share the same label on a legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have line of best fit and marker points plotted. I would like them to share the same legend label.

Here is the incorrect view of the graph:

[image]

Minimum example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.plot([0,7,8,9],[10,11,12,14], '-', label = '1')
plt.plot([1,2,3],[4,5,6], 'ro', label = '1')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Which markers/lines, exactly, do you want to be the same?

Comment: Could you post your code to generate to figure? Or maybe just a minimum example that shows the problem.

Comment: For example, I would like the dashed line for experiment 1 and the red dot for experiment 1 to be changed to the icons on the same line, labelled 'Experiment 1'.

Comment: So you want one line in the legend, that says 'Experiment 1' but has two labels next to it, one for the line and one for the symbol?

Comment: @Scorsch Yes - exactly that

Comment: Have a look at this question: [Custom Legend in Matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570007/custom-legend-in-matplotlib)