# Subtitles within Matplotlib legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend, cartopy

I am doing some plotting with matplotlib, and I have a legend which tells the viewer which sensors the points were recorded with. There are multiple sensors of multiple types, and I'd like to have subtitles within the legend to tell the viewer what kind of sensor each group is. I have a working solution, but it's a bit of a hack, shown here:

[image]

When the legend is created, it accepts two important arguments: a list of legend markers, and a list of legend labels. My current solution is to set the subtitle marker to be a white box with a white outline, and have the subtitle lable be surrounded by two newline characters. It looks alright, but it would look much more professional if the subtitles were not indented. Two workarounds I have tried have been setting the subtitle's marker to None, and also setting the subtitle's marker to the desired subtitle string and its label to an empty string. Neither have worked. Does anyone have any experience with this? Thanks so much.

Comment: This is as close as I've gotten: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570007/custom-legend-in-matplotlib/21571063#21571063

Comment: Have you considered manually editing the svg? It's a last resort but unless you have a lot of figures, you could do that much faster than  finding a programmatic solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best I could come up with is to make a custom handler for a string.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.text as mtext


class LegendTitle(object):
    def __init__(self, text_props=None):
        self.text_props = text_props or {}
        super(LegendTitle, self).__init__()

    def legend_artist(self, legend, orig_handle, fontsize, handlebox):
        x0, y0 = handlebox.xdescent, handlebox.ydescent
        title = mtext.Text(x0, y0, r'\underline{' + orig_handle + '}', usetex=True, **self.text_props)
        handlebox.add_artist(title)
        return title


[line1] = plt.plot(range(10))
[line2] = plt.plot(range(10, 0, -1), 'o', color='red')
plt.legend(['Title 1', line1, 'Title 2', line2], ['', 'Line 1', '', 'Line 2'],
           handler_map={str: LegendTitle({'fontsize': 18})})

plt.show()
```

[image: output]

I based this on the example in http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html.

Comment: I'm very excited to get your solution up and running; it seems pretty brilliant. Unfortunately, when I try and run it on my machine, it produces the error: RuntimeError: LaTeX was not able to process the following string:
'\\\\underline{'

Any ideas on what's going on?

Comment: I was able to get it working by changing r'\underline{' + orig_handle + '}' to orig_handle, and also removing usetex = True. It doesn't come out underlined, but it totally works!

Comment: I like this solution very much. Additonally, the comment from user JabberwockStomp was useful for me.

Since I am using Python 3 and not Python 2, I had to replace `handler_map={basestring: LegendTitle({'fontsize': 18})}` by `handler_map={str: LegendTitle({'fontsize': 18})}`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simplified version for **Python 3** that **does not require LaTeX**. It is based on this simple plot that you can find in [seaborn documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html), but it should work with matplotlib as well.

```
import seaborn as sns
flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
sns.lineplot(data=flights, x="year", y="passengers", hue="month")
```

So to add the subtitles, you can use this code.

```
# Seaborn example
import seaborn as sns
flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
g = sns.lineplot(data=flights, x="year", y="passengers", hue="month")

# Here is where the magic happens
h,l = g.get_legend_handles_labels()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.text as mtext


class LegendTitle(object):
    def __init__(self, text_props=None):
        self.text_props = text_props or {}
        super(LegendTitle, self).__init__()

    def legend_artist(self, legend, orig_handle, fontsize, handlebox):
        x0, y0 = handlebox.xdescent, handlebox.ydescent
        title = mtext.Text(x0, y0, orig_handle,  **self.text_props)
        handlebox.add_artist(title)
        return title


# ['','2nd Title'], and ['',''] is a hackish to leave some 
# space between the titles
g.legend(['1st Title'] + h[:6] + ['','2nd Title'] + h[6:12], 
          ['']         + l[:6] + ['','']          + l[6:12],
           handler_map={str: LegendTitle({'fontsize': 16})},
          bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1)
        )
```

[image]