# How can I add an R^2 value to the legend of a seaborn barplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a seaborn barplot and a regression line graphed on top of it that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy8I7.png). As you can see, I have a legend that is automatically created with seaborn.barplot() and I am attempting to add the R^2 score with this:

```
g = sns.barplot(x='City/Town', y="Value", hue="Metric", data=df, ax=ax1)
h, l = g.get_legend_handles_labels()
g.legend(h + [lin_reg.score(X, Y)], l + ['R^2 score'], title="Legend")
```

It doesn't throw an error, in fact I know it's working because it changes the title to "Legend", but it also doesn't add the R^2.

Comment: What is `lin_reg.score(X, Y)`?

Comment: Hi, your code is incomplete. What is `X,Y`? Where is the other plot, your second axis, do you do something with it? Do you have an example dataset? And the same question as @Ynjxsjmh, what is `lin_reg.score(X, Y)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The legend() function expects a handle in the first argument, and I don't think you can use text as one of those. You can read more [help page for matplotlib legend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html)

One quick solution I can think of, is to make a blank rectangle for the line intended for R^2, below is an example using iris as an example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression 

df = sns.load_dataset("iris")
lin_reg = LinearRegression().fit(df[['petal_length']], df['sepal_length'])
r2 = lin_reg.score(df[['petal_length']], df['sepal_length'])

blank = Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc="w", fill=False, edgecolor='none', linewidth=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
sns.scatterplot(x='sepal_width', y="sepal_length", hue="species", data=df, ax=ax)

h, l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax.legend(h + [blank], l + [f'R^2 score = {r2:.3f}'], title="Legend")
```

[image]

I noticed you have a barplot with a few categories, so I am not sure how you can calculate R^2 from that. In any case, with the code above you should be able to add the R^2

Comment: [Subtitles within Matplotlib legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38463369/subtitles-within-matplotlib-legend) has an interesting trick to avoid the empty rectangle.

Comment: Thanks! This will work fine for my application.