# Subheadings in matplotlib legend with defined subsets of categories and a stacked plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

The pandas dataframe has the following form, where`Year` is the index:

```
      A:Cat1  A:Cat2  B:Cat1  B:Cat2  B:Cat3
Year                                        
1977     0.5    0.25    0.15     0.1     0.1
1981     0.2     NaN    0.40     0.1     0.2
1983     0.1    0.10    0.30     0.2     0.3
```

The important thing is that you have the same categories Cat1 and Cat2 in two different "super-categories", A and B. To plot the variations of all the categories, I use a stacked graph and use two different set of colors for each super-category. All those colors are saved in the list `colors`.

What I am doing right now to draw the graph is (`plt` is `pyplot`):

```
plt.stackplot(data.index.values,data.fillna(0).T.values,colors=colors,labels=data.columns.values)
plt.legend(loc="best")
```

This gives the following with the previous data:

[image: Result of previous code]

Now, what I would like to do is to avoid repeating the super-categories A and B in the legend, either by creating two distinct legends for each of the supercategories, or by having subheadings inside the same legend. I looked at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570007/subheadings-for-categories-within-matplotlib-custom-legend) concerning subheadings, but the point is that I would like to be able to specify the breaking point between the two columns of the legend, so just specifying  `ncol=2` does not work because it does not break at the right point since I don't have the same number of categories in each «supercategory».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try to add a placeholder to deal with unequal number of categories in each supercategory. Or use a horizontal group labels:

```
import io

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = """1977 0.5 0.25    0.15    0.1 0.1
1981    0.2 NaN 0.40    0.1 0.2
1983    0.1 0.10    0.30    0.2 0.3"""
t = [('A', 'Cat1'), 
     ('A', 'Cat2'), 
     ('B', 'Cat1'), 
     ('B', 'Cat2'), 
     ('B', 'Cat3')]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(t)
df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(s), names=index)
df.index.name = 'Year'
colors = ['b', 'c', 'k', 'g', 'w']
plt.stackplot(df.index.values,df.fillna(0).T.values,colors=colors)

ha = mlines.Line2D([], [], marker='None', linestyle='None')
hb = mlines.Line2D([], [], marker='None', linestyle='None')
ha1 = mpatches.Patch(color=colors[0], ec='k')
ha2 = mpatches.Patch(color=colors[1], ec='k')
hb1 = mpatches.Patch(color=colors[2], ec='k')
hb2 = mpatches.Patch(color=colors[3], ec='k')
hb3 = mpatches.Patch(color=colors[4], ec='k')
hblank = mpatches.Patch(visible=False)
l1 = plt.legend([ha, ha1, ha2, hblank, hb, hb1, hb2, hb3], 
                ['A', 'Cat1', 'Cat2', '', 'B', 'Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3'], 
                loc=2, ncol=2) # Two columns, vertical group labels
l2 = plt.legend([ha, hblank, hb, hblank, hblank, ha1, ha2, hb1, hb2, hb3], 
                ['A', '', 'B', '', '', 'Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3'], 
                loc=4, ncol=2) # Two columns, horizontal group labels

ax = plt.gca()
ax.add_artist(l1)
ax.get_xaxis().get_major_formatter().set_useOffset(False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh but of course that's the right answer ! I did not think of padding the legend with empty plots and labels. I also did not know that the option  `visible=False` existed. Many thanks !